# How to change constraint right hand side cplex in java

Tags: constraints, cplex

I would like to know how can I change the right hand side of a constraint after I have read a model in a file with CPLEX Java API.

Let's say I have the following code:

```
IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex();
        cplex.setParam(IloCplex.IntParam.RootAlg,IloCplex.Algorithm.Auto);
        cplex.importModel(filename);
        if ( cplex.solve() ) {
        // solve the model
         }
```

and I have a constraint "c0" and I want to solve the same model changing only the right hand side of this constraint. How can I change it before I solve the model again? I tried to look for examples in the installation package, but so far I missed how to do it.

There is a function setBounds(newLB, new UB), but I can't just write in my code 
c0.setBounds(new LB, new UB).

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution, but after some research I found that, by making:

```
String filename = "model.lp";
        IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex();
        cplex.setParam(IloCplex.IntParam.RootAlg,IloCplex.Algorithm.Auto);
        cplex.importModel(filename);
        IloLPMatrix lp = (IloLPMatrix)cplex.LPMatrixIterator().next();
        if(cplex.solve()){

            double[] x = cplex.getValues(lp);
            for (int j = 0; j < x.length; ++j){
                System.out.println("Nome: " + lp.getNumVar(j).getName() + " Valor: "   + x[j]);
            }
        }
        IloRange [] list =  lp.getRanges();
        for(int g = 0; g < list.length; ++g){
            System.out.println(list[g].getLB() + " <= " + list[g].getName() + " <= " + list[g].getUB());
            if(list[g].getName().equals("r1")){
                list[g].setBounds(6.5, 6.5);
            }
        }
```

I could get the constraint "r1" and change its limits. It gave the correct answer for a toy problem, at least.
However, when I try to solve the model for the second time, cplex gives me:
"Warning:  No solution found from 1 MIP starts."
I know that the solution of the first problem will not be a solution for the second program. From the research I made I understood, possibly wrongly, that, as the solution to the first problem is infeasible for the second, it will start from scratch because I have a MIP problem. So, would it be preferable if I just wrote the model again in file and loaded it again?